# What does Space exploration look like in a Future with no progress?

Tags: futurology, space-colonization

Let's say in 10 years Moore's law fails and computers hit a wall in their evolution. (because of electron tunneling or something similar). We can still write better code and stack more CPUs but they aren't getting smaller. Similarly, medical tech stalls; we can cure a lot of stuff, but 80 or so years is your life expectancy.

What does that future look like, say, a century down the road?

Most current SciFi has the idea that if you add a few years to a problem it will just go away. I think the idea of limits is more compelling so let's limit it.

What happens to Space exploration and colonies when medicine and computers no longer progress? Do we still go to Mars?, Venus? What would our Science Fiction be like?

Comment: Please don't repost a question because it gets put on hold. Rather, fix the original to correct the issues that caused it to be put on hold in the first place. Editing a question during the on hold grace period automatically nominates it for community review for reopening.

Comment: I apologize for the breach of protocol but I think the proof is in the pudding that this is a different question. Just going by the number and quality of the answers. Especially compared to the original un-edited question,

Answer (score 2):

Like today (+10 years). 
Most of the problems with space exploration depend on physics not CPU processing power or medicine.

You can have all the CPU power you want, but earth gravity is still 9.81 m/s2 and escape velocity is still about 28000 km/h so, while a better CPU can save some time in the project phase, you are stuck with the same problems as today, speaking of space exploration.

Moreover, we already know how to build multi-core CPU or supercomputer based on stacking a lot of CPUs, so in the future if we cannot build faster CPUs, we will just use more of them, and I don't think that space exploration will be much different from today (unless we don't find a way to send material into space at the cost of tens of dollars instead of tens thousand of dollars for every kilogram)

Answer (score 1):

Year 2000. Fastest supercomputer was introduced. It had power of whopping 1 Megaflop and was built to calculate nuclear explosions. It cost in the millions dollars.

Year 2009. Computer with same abilities was introduced. Not only could it calculate nuclear explosions, but it could also show on the screen. It was called Playstation 3.

Log scale is hard to understand. If Moore's law "fails" in 10 years, it still means that computers on our desks will be as performant as current supercomputers. That's a lot of power.

Also, current computers on Orion ship [are no better than your phone](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2855604/the-orion-spacecraft-is-no-smarter-than-your-phone.html), because space tech is built for reliability, not for speed.

So even if Moore's law fails in 10 years, the best space ship will have on board a computer from Core duo era. I assume the space tech will continue for next 30 years.

And after 30 years, you will have current supercomputer on board. I believe you can still do magic with that.

Comment: I think you've either got the years completely wrong, or your performance figures are off by orders of magnitude. The [CDC STAR-100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDC_STAR-100) was first ordered in August 1971 and could perform at 100 megaflops, up from its predecessor [CDC 7600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDC_7600) which could muster only 10-36 megaflops and was introduced in 1969. A 35.86 *teraflops* computer [was finished in 2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Simulator) and remained the fastest supercomputer until September 2004.

Comment: See also [Historical TOP500 supercomputers table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_supercomputing#Historical_TOP500_table), which goes back to 1993 at which point the peak speed was *already* 124.50 gigaflops. The teraflops limit was surpassed in 1997 with a 1.338 teraflops system, and the petaflops limit in 2008 with a 1.026-1.105 petaflops system.

Answer (score 0):

## First, Moore's Law is not a law.

Yes, I know it's called "Moore's Law" in myriad textbooks and journals, and I'm certainly not suggesting you misspoke! It's one of those unfortunate names that stuck and we have to live with, but for this question, I believe it's important that I supply a slightly better definition: Moore's Law is not a law, but an observation (and a darned good one at that!) But this means that it cannot "fail"; it's just an observation with some analysis.

## Ways around it

There are also all sorts of ways we could pass Moore's law.

- Quantum computing has been around the corner for a couple of decades or so
- There have been some experiments with supercooled paramagnetic atoms that could drastically increase storage density.
- Better cooling methods would allow more power ("overclocking" or simply more power-hungry chips).

And, a big one:

## Faster networks = more cloud computing

Cloud computing is a good thing, even now, but due to the slow networks in between, many applications that *could* use distributed computing are forced to run their own equipment locally. However, as wired and wireless networks get faster, more and more applications could use cloud computing, which means we can take the idea of a multi-core CPU and multiply that by *thousands* of computers spread across the globe (or even in orbit around the Earth). This is a subtle point, but an interesting one to explore, at least in my opinion.

And what does cloud computing have to do with a question about space exploration? At least for a while, the ship would remain in contact with Earth. Even after that, the ship could easily have its own on-board "cloud" of general purposes low-power lightweight servers.

## Ways to make the technology wall inevitable

I wouldn't personally have the characters or narrator shaking their proverbial fist at Gord Moore, because even in fiction, I think that would be a weak argument, given the many ways your people could steer around that "wall". You *could* say something like, "for years we were worried we wouldn't be able to sustain the growth that Moore had observed in past decades, but what really stopped us from colonizing Mars was something much much worse..."

- **Energy consumption.** It takes so many $\text{W} \times \text{sec } \ (\text{Joules})$ to take a square root, and there's only so much you can reduce that with increased efficiency. But the kicker is, unlike chip density, energy consumption cannot be parallelized away; total heat gets *worse* when you have to involve more machines (more overhead). And for every Joule of energy you need for a calculation, you'll exhaust a Joule of heat somewhere else. That's hard to deal with on Earth, but even harder in space as it is hard to recycle heat, and hard to shed what can't be recycled.
- **Materials shortages.** Most of the components in modern computers are made of relatively common materials, but there are a few that are in relatively short supply. For example, the entire worldwide reserve of Indium tin oxide (used to coat LCD touch screens) could [run out within the next ten years](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/computing-components/the-pc-rare-metals-crisis-921363), and that's just one example.

## Medicine

How do computing and medicine relate to each other (per your question, that is, since you were asking about both)?

Answer (score -1):

That question would be similar to, what when we cannot place any more gears to the crank? How would we compute stuff? Or this building will not fit anymore radio tubes or this board cannot hold any more transistors or this board cannot hold any more IC's - By now you should know where i'm going.

[image] If you take a quick look at the following image you will discover the lack of a CPU, central processing unit. This is an IBM computer from 81, it is carrying a lot of IC chips but not the architecture a person from the 90's is used to.

Just because more's law is about to fail does not mean the technological development is about to slow down.

Right now we are looking at 2 huge prospects in the technological terms.

1. Is the quantum computer, where you before had a 0 or a 1, like the flip-switch in your home, the quantum computer is like a dimmer that contains any floating point number between 0 and 1 (thats a lot of numbers), increasing the calculation power of a small 4 bit cpu by alot.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing

2. Biological computer, we are trying to mimic the brain, the brain is rather small and is considered as powerful (some think it is more powerful) than [blue gene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Gene). Copying the brain/nerves would create a fast reliable computer able to calculate a lot at the same time. Backside is that the brain needs food.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biocomputer

Disclaimer: the descriptions may be simplified, use links to get more sophisticated description.

Comment: Actually, unlike today, the IBM 5150 motherboard (which that looks an awful lot like) basically *only* held the CPU, *some of* the RAM, keyboard/casette ports, expansion slots, and support circuitry. See [here](http://www.mtmscientific.com/pc-retro.html) ([this](http://www.mtmscientific.com/pc.jpg)) and even better [here](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/roger.broughton/museum/micros/fullsize/201313q.jpg); the CPU is near the top left in all, behind the lower round socket (I don't know off hand if that's casette or kbd). Looks like Intel in your photo and Broughton's, and AMD in the modern kit one.

Comment: Ok maybe i used a wrong picture but the point of the post is the same, the first computers was made from IC registers and processors and didn't run on a central processing unit. https://youtu.be/HyznrdDSSGM as example, so the point is the same. Please read the disclaimer.

Comment: The IBM PC (model 5150) was hardly the "first computer". It wasn't even anywhere near the first personal computer, let alone the first electronic computer. It wasn't even *IBM's* first personal computer (as in "a computer meant for use by one person"). Personal computers as we think of them today have never *not* used CPUs; before IBM's foray into the field with the 8088 CPU, lots of personal computers used e.g. the 6502 or 8080. I say it again: the motherboard shown *does not show a lack of a CPU;* the CPU is quite prominent, *the CPU just looks different from the way the chip looks today*.

Comment: In fact, the invention of the CPU-on-an-IC was essentially what made what we today think of as personal computers *possible*. Discrete component logic, or even CPU-on-a-board as was sometimes done previously, was just too large physically. Your disclaimer unfortunately makes this answer a bit like showing a horse carriage and pointing out that early cars had no driver's seat, then saying that the description is simplified. If you (or someone else) wants to learn more, I suggest heading on over to the [retrocomputing.se] SE, which specializes in the history of (primarily) electronic computers.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling are you in a discussion mood? The answer is still valid you are nitpicking details not interesting for the answer. The quesiton was about the future of the computer vs moores law. I gave a bit of origin of the law, and a possible solution. If you want to write 2 long text about the Model  XXXX was wrong on the picture, go ahead, if you want to downvote, do so... But the answer is still a valid answer to the question. And it looks like you are just looking for mistakes in my answers ripping up 22 month old answer like that.